# Prove that $2^\mathbb{N}$ is equinumerous to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was thinking using the fact that $[0,1]$ is equinumerous with $\mathbb{R}$, but i cant think of a bijection from there to $2^\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: You mean $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{N}$ in the title?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_the_continuum#Cardinal_equalities

Comment: I was tempted to close this as a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1449619/cardinality-of-the-reals-and-the-power-set-of-naturals instead.

Answer (score 0):

For $2^{\mathbb{N}} \le \mathbb{R}$ consider the map $T:2^{\mathbb{N}}\to \mathbb{R}$ given by

$$T(f)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f(n)}{10^n}$$

For $\mathbb{R}\le 2^{\mathbb{N}}$, note that $2^{\mathbb{N}}\sim \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\sim \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q})$

and use the map

$$
S(x)=\{q\in\mathbb{Q}:q<x\}
$$

for $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Now you just have to show that these maps are injective. I believe it's not very hard from here